# Unable to run s3 sink connector for persisting kafka data on Minio

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, minio

I have a Kubernetes cluster running with minikube, inside the cluster is running one kafka pod, one zookeeper pod and minio pod everyone with it service. Everything looks working properly. I have a minio topic generated called minio-topic working on kafka, and minio has one bucket called kafka-bucket, I have tried to run s3-sink-connector with this properties:

```
name=s3-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=minio_topic
s3.region=us-east-1
s3.bucket.name=kafka-bucket
s3.part.size=5242880
flush.size=3
store.url=http://l27.0.0.1:9000/
storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage
#format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.avro.AvroFormat
schema.generator.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator
format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner

schema.compatibility=NONE
```

After running the connector i am getting this error

```
[2020-05-06 18:00:46,238] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=s3-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable 
exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:179)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at io.confluent.connect.storage.StorageFactory.createStorage(StorageFactory.java:55)
    at io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkTask.start(S3SinkTask.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:301)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:189)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at io.confluent.connect.storage.StorageFactory.createStorage(StorageFactory.java:50)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hostname cannot be null
    at com.amazonaws.util.AwsHostNameUtils.parseRegion(AwsHostNameUtils.java:79)
    at com.amazonaws.util.AwsHostNameUtils.parseRegionName(AwsHostNameUtils.java:59)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.computeSignerByURI(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:277)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.setEndpoint(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:229)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.setEndpoint(AmazonS3Client.java:688)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:362)
    at 
com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.configureMutableProperties(AwsClientBuilder.java:337)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:38)
    at io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage.newS3Client(S3Storage.java:96)
    at io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage.<init>(S3Storage.java:65)
    ... 15 more
```

The credentials are well defined into .aws/credentials, Does anyone know what possibly be the mistake in the configuration?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hostname cannot be null, it seems you are not correctly passing the hostname

Answer (score 0):

`hostname cannot be null at com.amazonaws.util.AwsHostNameUtils.parseRegion`

I suggest you read up on [the Minio blog](https://blog.minio.io/journaling-kafka-messages-with-s3-connector-and-minio-83651a51045d) on setting the `store.url` correctly as well as verify which region your Minio cluster thinks it's running on.